# How to bind textures to different register in dx12?

Tags: hlsl, directx-12

I have two texture and a texture array. I am trying to bind the two textures to t1 and the texture array to t2.
The hlsl may like this

```
Texture2D    gDiffuseMap : register(t0);
Texture2DArray gDiffuseMaps : register(t1);
```

I create a descriptor range which has 2 descriptors.

```
CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texTable;
texTable.Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 2, 0);
```

But I don't know how to bind the descriptors to registers.

Answer (score 5):

The communication between the shaders and the GPU for DirectX 12 is handled through root signatures. For two textures, you have two choices for how to bind it.

## Two textures in one descriptor table

The first is to bind them together but this requires that the target descriptors be continuous. That's what you have started down the path of doing.

```
// HLSL syntax
#define DualTextureRS \
"RootFlags ( ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT |" \
"            DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |" \
"            DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |" \
"            DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS )," \
"DescriptorTable ( SRV(t0, numDescriptors = 2), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL )," \
"DescriptorTable ( Sampler(s0, numDescriptors = 2), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL )," \
"CBV(b0)"

// C++ code built root-signature
enum RootParameterIndex
{
    TextureSRVBase,
    TextureSamplerBase,
    ConstantBuffer,
    RootParameterCount
};

{
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAGS rootSignatureFlags =
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT |
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS;

    CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::RootParameterCount] = {};
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::ConstantBuffer].InitAsConstantBufferView(0, 0, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);

    // Textures
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE textureRange(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 2, 0);
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE textureSamplerRange(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SAMPLER, 2, 0);
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::TextureSRVBase].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &textureRange, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::TextureSamplerBase].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &textureSamplerRange, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);

    // Create the root signature
    CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rsigDesc = {};
    rsigDesc.Init(_countof(rootParameters), rootParameters, 0, nullptr, rootSignatureFlags);

    ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> rootSignature;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pSignature;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pError;
    HRESULT hr = D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rsigDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, pSignature.GetAddressOf(), pError.GetAddressOf());
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = device->CreateRootSignature(0, pSignature->GetBufferPointer(), pSignature->GetBufferSize(),
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&rootSignature)
            );
    }
}
```

And then you'd bind it:

```
commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(rootSignature.Get());
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::TextureSRVBase, texture1); // Second texture will be (texture1+1)
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::TextureSamplerBase, texture1Sampler); // Second sampler will be (texture1Sampler+1)
```

## Two descriptor tables

The second is to bind them as two different descriptor ranges so you can bind two arbitrary textures:

```
// HLSL syntax
#define DualTextureRS \
"RootFlags ( ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT |" \
"            DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |" \
"            DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |" \
"            DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS )," \
"DescriptorTable ( SRV(t0), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL )," \
"DescriptorTable ( Sampler(s0), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL )," \
"DescriptorTable ( SRV(t1), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL )," \
"DescriptorTable ( Sampler(s1), visibility = SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL )," \
"CBV(b0)"

// C++ code built root-signature
enum RootParameterIndex
{
    Texture1SRV,
    Texture1Sampler,
    Texture2SRV,
    Texture2Sampler,
    ConstantBuffer,
    RootParameterCount
};

{
    D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAGS rootSignatureFlags =
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT |
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_DOMAIN_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_GEOMETRY_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS |
        D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_DENY_HULL_SHADER_ROOT_ACCESS;

    CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::RootParameterCount] = {};
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::ConstantBuffer].InitAsConstantBufferView(0, 0, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);

    // Texture 1
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texture1Range(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 1, 0);
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texture1SamplerRange(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SAMPLER, 1, 0);
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::Texture1SRV].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &texture1Range, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::Texture1Sampler].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &texture1SamplerRange, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);

    // Texture 2
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texture2Range(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 1, 1);
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texture2SamplerRange(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SAMPLER, 1, 1);
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::Texture2SRV].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &texture2Range, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);
    rootParameters[RootParameterIndex::Texture2Sampler].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &texture2SamplerRange, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_PIXEL);

    // Create the root signature
    CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rsigDesc = {};
    rsigDesc.Init(_countof(rootParameters), rootParameters, 0, nullptr, rootSignatureFlags);

    ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> rootSignature;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pSignature;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pError;
    HRESULT hr = D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rsigDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, pSignature.GetAddressOf(), pError.GetAddressOf());
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = device->CreateRootSignature(0, pSignature->GetBufferPointer(), pSignature->GetBufferSize(),
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&rootSignature)
            );
    }
}
```

And then you'd bind it:

```
commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(rootSignature.Get());
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::Texture1SRV, texture1);
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::Texture1Sampler, texture1Sampler);
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::Texture2SRV, texture2);
commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(RootParameterIndex::Texture2Sampler, texture2Sampler);
```

The second form is the one I use in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) because it's more flexible.